Removing Footnotes Microsoft Word VBA
I need a word macro in VBA that will scan through a document and remove all footnotes from the footer and insert all the text associated with that footnote in the place of the footnote superscript in the paragraph. The macro should remove the superscript footnote reference number in the body text and replace it with notation (in the same place as the footnote),"[Footnote X: ]" with the X= to the footnote number, and the unique footnote text should be in the notation with the correct footnote number.
For example:
Body text before macro:
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.39"
body text post macro:
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.[Footnote 39: (reference text).]"
Many macros I developed would not run or would not even alter the text.
